# is there a way to keep updating GL contents with paintGL in QT?

Tags: pyqt

I'm writing a video player with two QGLWidgets -- a controller(a menu with buttons like select, play) and a viewer(where the video actually gets played). For the viewer, I have the paintGL function calling the display function I implemented to update each frame. But unless I resize the viewer window or switch between the two windows, the viewer doesn't update itself and just stops on the third frame.

In other post, I found that I have very little control over when paintGL gets called (resizing is one of the cases where it gets called). Is there a way to work around the this?

Thanks!

Edited:
So I have two classes: Player and Viewer (both QGLWidgets)
When running the program, a player (the controller) will be displayed, and users can choose a video and hit the play button. The player handles the play button in the way that it creates a Viewer which plays the selected video.

```
def handlePlayButton(self):
    self.viewer = Viewer(self.filepath)
    self.viewer.show()
```

And the Viewer is initialized and updated as following

```
def paintGL(self):
    self.display() //update the window with the current frame
    glViewport(0, 0, self.vid.getWidth(), self.vid.getHeight())

def resizeGL(self, w, h):
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()

def initializeGL(self):
    //initialize the shaders with other libraries
```

Comment: Please include some actual code in your question.